# Should I worry about implementing client side caching if I am using firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Say I have data fetching code like this

```
firestore().collection("USERS").get(userId1)
```

And say my app uses this user in multiple places. Normally with a rest API I would build some sort of data persistence layer, where I map id => users and let my app reuses the in memory data.

In the case of firebase though is it efficient to just call

```
firestore().collection("USERS").get(userId1)
```

Whenever I need that user model and just let the firebase sdk figure out if networking needs to happen.

Comment: Firestore will by default already cache those in a local database, and allow querying them while you're offline. Whether that is enough for your needs, only you can determine.

Comment: Yeah should be enough. Basically I just don't want to worry about having to implement caching logic for this super prototype level app. 

But at the same time I dont want to code myself into a situation where I am making 100s of unneeded DB calls

Comment: The use case is not clear. If I have an app and want to use a variable to represent pi, I would use `let pi = 3.14` and then use it throughout the app. It wouldn't be very efficient to create a text file, store it a drive and read the text file each time pi is needed. Why *wouldn't* you  read the user data once from Firestore and store it in a user object to be used throughout the app. You could attach an observer so if the user data changes your app is notified of that change and could then update the object. Perhaps more information would help generate a more accurate answer.

Comment: Because implementing would be a lot of really boring work. 
Then I would have an extra layer of possible bugs. 

So if I can have a library handle it for me Id rather do that.